# how can i get the internal ID/name of the terms in a managed metadata column?

Tags: metadata, sharepoint-designer

I'm creating a SPD workflow where if the term in the managed metadata column = X, an action happens but the only way SPD will do the proper comparison to "X" is by using the internal 
ID of the term - in the following format: “-1;#TermLabel|xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx”

Is there a way to get a list of all the terms with the internal ID?

Comment: I dont think you can do that. You might have to create a custom sharepoint designer activity for that: http://msmvps.com/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2010/12/26/develop-custom-workflow-activity-for-sharepoint-2010-workflow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the GUID's of a few particular terms and hardcode those in your workflow, you could:

1. type the terms in a Edit Properties dialog while watching the webservice calls with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), or
2. if the column is in a document library, create a Word document in that library and using Word's document information panel edit type the terms you're looking for. When done look in the %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\TermSets folder on your PC, it contains the xml file with the cached terms.

Try to make your workflow only look at the GUID (xxx-xx-etc) part, that's the part that's constant.